# Caching azure blob html content in private container

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Can I cache blob content in a private container? All caching examples I see online are done in a public container. Thanks

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by `cache blob content`?

Comment: Do you mean the CDN network?

Comment: I am trying to cache the contents stored on azure blob storage. Similar to what was done in the following link, but in a private container. 

http://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/08/11/save-money-by-setting-cache-control-on-windows-azure-blobs/